# POST request always returns "Disallowed Key Characters"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, httprequest, python-requests

I want to retrieve Atmospheric particulate matter values from a table (sadly the site is not in english, so feel free to ask for everything): I failed with the combination of `BeautifulSoup` and GET request sent with `requests`, since table is filled with Bootstrap dinamically and a parser like `BeautifulSoup` can't find values which still must be inserted.

With Firebug I checked every angle of the page, and I found out that by selecting a different day of the table, a POST request is sent (the site, as you can see in `Referer`, is `http://www.arpat.toscana.it/temi-ambientali/aria/qualita-aria/bollettini/index/regionale/`, where the table is):

```
POST /temi-ambientali/aria/qualita-aria/bollettini/aj_dati_bollettini HTTP/1.1
Host: www.arpat.toscana.it    
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
Accept: */*    
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://www.arpat.toscana.it/temi-ambientali/aria/qualita-aria/bollettini/index/regionale/26-12-2016
Content-Length: 114
Cookie: [...]
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

With the following params:

```
v_data_osservazione=26-12-2016&v_tipo_bollettino=regionale&v_zona=&csrf_test_name=b88d2517c59809a529
b6f8141256e6ca
```

Data in the answer are in JSON format.

So I started to craft my personal POST request, in order to directly get the JSON data which will fill the table.

In the params, in addition to the date, a `csrf_test_name` is required: here I discovered this site is protected against [CSRF vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery); in order to perform a correct query in params, I need a CSRF token: that's why I perform a GET request to the site (see `Referer` in POST request for the URL) and get CSRF token from the cookie like this:

```
r = get(url)
csrf_token = r.cookies["csrf_cookie_name"]
```

At end of the day, with my CSRF token and POST request ready, I send it...and with status code 200, I always get `Disallowed Key Characters.`!

Looking for this error, I always see posts about CodeIgniter, which (I think) is not what I need: I tried every combination of headers and parameters, yet nothing changed. Before giving up on `BeautifulSoup` and `requests` and start learning `Selenium`, I'd like to figure out what the problem is: `Selenium` is too high level, low level libraries like `BeautifulSoup` and `requests` let me learn lot of useful things, so I'd prefer continue learning with these two.

Here's the code:

```
from requests import get, post
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import json

url = "http://www.arpat.toscana.it/temi-ambientali/aria/qualita-aria/bollettini/index/regionale/" # + %d-%m-%Y
yesterday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1)
date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(yesterday), '%Y-%m-%d')
yesterday_string = str(date_object.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))

full_url = url + yesterday_string
print("REFERER " + full_url)

r = get(url)
csrf_token = r.cookies["csrf_cookie_name"]
print(csrf_token)

# preparing headers for POST request
headers = {
    "Host": "www.arpat.toscana.it",
    "Accept" : "*/*",
    "Accept-Language" : "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip, deflate",
    "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "X-Requested-With" : "XMLHttpRequest", # XHR
    "Referer" : full_url,
    "DNT" : "1", 
    "Connection" : "keep-alive"
}

# preparing POST parameters (to be inserted in request's body)
payload_string = "v_data_osservazione="+yesterday_string+"&v_tipo_bollettino=regionale&v_zona=&csrf_test_name="+csrf_token
print(payload_string)

# data -- (optional) Dictionary, bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the Request.

# json -- (optional) json data to send in the body of the Request.
req = post("http://www.arpat.toscana.it/temi-ambientali/aria/qualita-aria/bollettini/aj_dati_bollettini",
    headers = headers, json = payload_string
)

print("URL " + req.url)

print("RESPONSE:")
print('\t'+str(req.status_code))
print("\tContent-Encoding: " + req.headers["Content-Encoding"])
print("\tContent-type: " + req.headers["Content-type"])
print("\tContent-Length: " + req.headers["Content-Length"])
print('\t'+req.text)
```

Comment: if you would like to keep learning and using the necessary requests for your necessities, but with help on cookies, referring and header management, I would recommend you to check [`scrapy`](https://scrapy.org)

Comment: I want to know so badly what is wrong with my code, but `scrapy` may be worthy a try. I'm gonna put `pip` at work right now, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: you can use http://httpbin.org to send `POST` and it sends back all data which it receives - and then you can compare it with data send by browser to server. it helps to find differences in requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me:

- I use `request.Session()` and it keeps all cookies
- I use `data=` instead of `json=`
- finally I don't need all commented elements
- to compare browser requests and code requests I used [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) web debugging proxy application

code:

```
import requests
import datetime

#proxies = {
#    'http': 'http://localhost:8888',
#    'https': 'http://localhost:8888',
#}

s = requests.Session()
#s.proxies = proxies # for test only

date = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
date = date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

# --- main page ---

url = "http://www.arpat.toscana.it/temi-ambientali/aria/qualita-aria/bollettini/index/regionale/"

print("REFERER:", url+date)

r = s.get(url)

# --- data ---

csrf_token = s.cookies["csrf_cookie_name"]

#headers = {
    #'User-Agent': 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0',
    #"Host": "www.arpat.toscana.it",
    #"Accept" : "*/*",
    #"Accept-Language" : "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    #"Accept-Encoding" : "gzip, deflate",
    #"Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    #"X-Requested-With" : "XMLHttpRequest", # XHR
    #"Referer" : url,
    #"DNT" : "1", 
    #"Connection" : "keep-alive"
#}

payload = {
    'csrf_test_name': csrf_token,   
    'v_data_osservazione': date,
    'v_tipo_bollettino': 'regionale',
    'v_zona': None,
}

url = "http://www.arpat.toscana.it/temi-ambientali/aria/qualita-aria/bollettini/aj_dati_bollettini"
r = s.post(url, data=payload) #, headers=headers)

print('Status:', r.status_code)
print(r.json())
```

proxy:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It works indeed, thank you! `Session` and `Charles` apart, it seems I was passing params to POST request in the wrong way.

Comment: it is problem with date - there is no information for `28-12-2016` yet.

Comment: You are right, I deleted the comment after realizing the data were still to be loaded and I deleted the comment: it was 2 am, I was quite tired xD not very polite since you managed to read it and answer me again, so thank you again